# Pre-process validation of an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that creates many `INSERT INTO` statements using Dynamic SQL. I have no control over the data that I am attempting to insert and the values being inserted are derived from a

```
SELECT * FROM sourceTable
```

Occasionally, when inserting, a foreign key constraint is triggered (the data is being taken from environment A and being inserted into environment B so it is possible certain other tables have not been kept up to date)

My question is - is there a way to pre-process validate all my `INSERT` statements for any errors (foreign key constraint or otherwise) before executing them? Or do I need to create checkpoints and use the rollback functionality?

**---OVERVIEW OF PROCESS**

We create tables on environment A (source) containing subsets of data    based on a selection criteria

Using the SQL Export Wizard, these tables are copied across to environment B (target)

A stored procedure is run to import the data from these tables into the corresponding
   tables on environment B. This sp uses the `INSERT INTO tableA SELECT
   * FROM tableAFromSource` command within a dynamic SQL loop containing all the table names

This approach is used due to external factors we cannot control (servers cannot be linked, data structures, permissions on servers etc)

Comment: Could you provide more details? I get the idea this is part of an ETL process, but for such processes usually there's no need for dynamic SQL ... other thing, have you considered using `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`?

Comment: @GerardoLima - main post updated with details of the process. How would using MERGE avoid any FK contraints being violated?

Comment: From MSDN "[MERGE] Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table." [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx]

Comment: A warning to use MERGE with caution (if at all!) - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ - plus I still don't see how MERGE gets around a FK constraint. This is getting off-topic from my original question around pre-process validation.

Comment: The only way I know of is wrapping the whole batch in a transaction (yes, that's a big OW for large amounts of data). How could you test a generic data modification batch of statements? What if I try to insert the same row twice? So yeah, if you *need* transactional integrity, you should probably use transactions.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any type of pre-processing that checks what would be the result of any given query, but it's often easy to check for conditions using plain T-SQL. If you just want to avoid the primary key constraint violations, you can use the following variation of the query you provided (considering `Id` the primary key):

```
INSERT INTO tableA
SELECT *
FROM tableAFromSource src
WHERE src.Id NOT IN ( SELECT tba.Id FROM tableA tba );
```